# How do I create angular component that can be used only once?

Tags: angular7

I am trying to create a component that could be rendered only in one place. If the same component is initialized in some different place it should automatically destroy the existing instance of that component before creating new one.

This is for creating custom reusable modal component. I am trying to avoid external library. 
I don't want two modals showing on the top of each other.

I tried using query selector on oninit to detect if that component is already rendered somewhere else. But it didn't work out.

I want to be able to detect if the component is rendered and if found any destroy it before creating another.

Comment: maintain a record of the component in a service - if there is a new component initialized some place, remove the previous instance

Comment: sounds legit. I will try that